# How do I get voices on arch linux?

Tags: arch-linux

```
$ spd-say -L                   
Failed to get voice list.
```

I have speech-dispatcher installed and running on arch Linux

Comment: Try to add packages: `speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins`, `speech-dispatcher-espeak`, `speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng`, `speech-dispatcher-festival` if it won't help, add then: `festival`,  `mbrola`,  `espeak-data`, `espeak-ng`

Comment: now nothing works :(

Comment: Argh... not good, did you read [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Festival) ?

Comment: You need to install `espeakup`. ([source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Install_Arch_Linux_with_accessibility_options)). (Note that I previously posted this as an answer but it was deleted because @mokubai mistakenly thought the solution would be found on the linked page. It is not. The solution **IS**: install `espeakup`. That's it. This will solve this question. Please undelete my answer.)

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yay -S espeakup`

It asked me if I wanted to uninstall `espeak-ng` I said yes, but it appeared to re-install it anyway.